# Loading image JSON to list view

Tags: android, json, web-services, listview

I have a list view which has an image and an image name, I am loading the data from JSON web service and display it in a List View.

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "my url";

    // JSON Node names
     String Doctors = "Doctors";
     String DoctorName = "DoctorName";
     String ImageName = "ImageName";

     // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray Doctor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            Doctor = json.getJSONArray(Doctors);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < Doctor.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = Doctor.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("TAG", "JSON IS: " + Doctor.toString());

                String imageBaseDirectory = "http://92.253.101.239:81/sudandoctors/UploadedFiles/";
                String imageName = c.getString(ImageName);//get image name from json parsing;
                System.err.println("imageBaseDirectory = "+imageBaseDirectory);
                System.err.println("imageName = "+imageName);
                System.err.println("two = "+imageBaseDirectory+imageName);
                image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageBaseDirectory+imageName));

                String n = imageBaseDirectory+imageName;
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put("DoctorName", c.getString("DoctorName"));
                map.put("ImageName", n);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { DoctorName, ImageName }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.ImageView });

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

I got this error

```
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.jsonparsing/com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:61)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-13 14:06:07.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     ... 11 more
```

and when I use the link in my browser it actually give me the pic, so what is the problem

Comment: whats their in line number 61?

Comment: image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageBaseDirectory+imageName));

Comment: why are you trying to set imageUri 2 times?

Comment: @RandHalim : ok you will need a custom adapter to set image src from server  instead of default adapter

Comment: there're so many errors in this code, I can only suggest you to stop it and go learn a bit more about Android development, memory allocation, object creation, activity life-cycle, UI thread, design for responsiveness, etc.

Comment: in almost all modern IDE you can use debuger ... just add breakpoint before this line... then watch `image` var ... if you don't know how to debug you should learn(or stop programming) .. SO is not online debugging service

Answer (score 1):

[Try this.. does exactly what you want](http://imagelistviewdynamic.blogspot.in/)

Another example of stackoverflow question.

[To display images in a listview, you need to create a list adapter class that extends from BaseAdapter and create each view there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698135/android-loading-image-from-json-url-into-listview)

Above Codes works fine. Do changes according to your requirements.

or  [go to this awesome example LazyList. shows how to load images in listview. It make you to understand nicely](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)